# determine if multiplication output fits into max value of 64 bits

Tags: c++, c

I have a multiplication line that can result in output greater than 64 bit values. (max i can hold).

I want to determine what is the best way to determine if the output is greater than 64 bits.

I have tried some things like.

```
uint64_t val1, val2, val3;
if ((val1 * val2 * val3 ) > UINT64_MAX) {
    //warning message
}
else {
    //do something
}
```

variables are initialized to some values.

Comment: you can read the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/best-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534107/detecting-multiplication-of-uint64-t-integers-overflow-with-c

Answer (score 4):

A multiplication `a * b` of two unsigned (!) integer numbers of arbitrary size, let's call this type `T`, will overflow if and only if the result would be greater than the maximum number `T` can hold. The standard library can access the maximum number of any type `T` using [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits).

The above statement can also be written as: `a * b` will overflow if and only if `a > max(T) / b`, which is the same as `b > max(T) / a` (where `/` is an integer division and `max(T)` is the maximum number `T` can hold).

Example: Let's say `T = uint8_t`, so `max(T) == 255`. A couple of examples for demonstration:

```
a              |  16 |  15 |  14
b              |  16 |  17 |  18
---------------------------------
a * b          | 256 | 255 | 252
overflow?      | yes |  no |  no
---------------------------------
max(T)/b       |  15 |  15 |  14
a > max(T)/b?  | yes |  no |  no
```

Use this method to check if a multiplication `a * b` will overflow:

```
#include <limits.h>

template<typename T>
bool multiplicationWillOverflow(T a, T b) {
    return a > std::numeric_limits<T>::max() / b;
}
```

Then, use this method twice on your product of three numbers:

```
uint64_t val1, val2, val3;
if (multiplicationWillOverflow(val1, val2)) {
    //warning message
}

uint64_t product12 = val1 * val2, 
else if (multiplicationWillOverflow(product12, val3)) {
    //warning message
}

uint64_t product123 = product12 * val3;
```

Another option is to encapsulate the multiplication and the check in *one* method. *Throw an exception* if an overflow occurs.

```
template<typename T>
T safeMultiplication(T a, T b) {
    if (a > std::numeric_limits<T>::max() / b)
        throw ...;
    else
        return a * b;
}
```

You can encapsulate this behavior in a custom type, which overloads arithmetic operators and throws if an overflow would happen.

*Don't use exceptions* if you expect overflows as "normal behavior" / under "normal circumstances". In such cases, use an error parameter / a flag in a custom type instead.

A similar thing is done in floating point arithmetic with `NaN` exceptional states: Continuing a calculation with a `NaN` value will result in `NaN` again. A similar implementation for flagging overflow in your custom type will make sure you can detect overflow in chained calculations, like your product of three numbers, easily. The point about a custom type is that you don't have to write the expression to be calculated twice: As the calculation itself plus the overflow checking in advance.